# How to get element data field using jquery in nested form

Tags: jquery, html, element

This is jquery, code, it always returns ID = 1 when you click on "GENERAL" or inner section like "CSS ISSUES". While i am trying to get ID of the Li clicked.

```
 <ul id="faq_list" class="list-unstyled">
       <li data-type="parent" data-value="1">
                <a href="javascript:;">General</a>
                <div class="subdata" id="target_1">
                   <ul>             
                        <li data-type="parent" data-value="5">
                      <a href="javascript:;">CSS Issues</a>
                      <div class="subdata" id="target_5"></div>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
       </li>
       </ul>
```

Here is JQUERY CODE

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $("li").on('click',function(e) {


            var id = $(this).attr('data-value'); alert(id);
            load_data(id);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop event bubbling using [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```
$("li").on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert(id);
    load_data(id);
});
```

See **[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/rtsyps73/)**, or run the following snippet for a demo.

```js
$("li").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
  alert(id);
  load_data(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="faq_list" class="list-unstyled">
  <li data-type="parent" data-value="1"> <a href="javascript:;">General</a>

    <div class="subdata" id="target_1">
      <ul>
        <li data-type="parent" data-value="5"> <a href="javascript:;">CSS Issues</a>

          <div class="subdata" id="target_5"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank You, Actually i had tried e.stopPropagation() earlier, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: This code will not work with ajax returned data, that was actually my problem. e.stopPropagation()